# Нужно нарисовать график (создание осей)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Нужно сделать такой график, есть массив с y и x (значение преметно такие 0.32(поэтому умножал на 100))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал код для создание графика, но нужно создать оси (с обозначениями (от 0 до 3 по x))

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath(); 
ctx.translate(0, canvas.height);
ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2);
ctx.moveTo((arrY[0]*100)+150, arrX[0]*100); 
for(i=1; i<22; i++){
    ctx.lineTo((arrY[i]*100)+150, arrX[i]*100); 
}

ctx.stroke();
```

ПОдскажите как их можно сделать

Comment: Из слова `canvas` можно догадаться, что там можно рисовать (логично), сначала рисуете "сетку" по координатам (это вот самое простое), потом "пишите" обозначения этой сетки, а уже поверх всего этого рисуете график.

Comment: Подскажите а как можно на осях сделать числовые значения?

Comment: [.fillText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText)